# deploy war in tomcat through command line in windows

Tags: tomcat, url, command-line, deployment

We need to deploy war file or directory by URL in tomcat through command line or by groovy script, i have the url

http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?war=foo
http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?war=bar.war

but how to execute this url in command line/ groovy script in windows OS, thanks in advance.

Comment: In groovy try: new URL('http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?war=bar.war').text

Comment: thanks Smirnov for the reply, but need command to execute this url in windows

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you want to execute a Groovy script, you're gonna need to install Groovy. Any reason you want to use Groovy specifically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/q/483754/122257